# macro to copy visible cells from excel to email body?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, copy

I would like to copy Range("A2:K21") of commentary (sheetname) into the body of an outlook email. Can someone suggest some code. I am trying to use the below code but its not copying the excel range to the body. What am I missing? This macro is attaching the specific sheet to the email as an attachment.

```
Option Explicit
 
Sub EmailandSaveCellValue()
     
     'Variable declaration
    Dim oApp As Object, _
    oMail As Object, _
    wb As Workbook, _
    FileName As String, MailSub As String, MailTxt As String
     
     '*************************************************  ********
     'Set email details; Comment out if not required
    Const MailTo = Worksheets("Mappings").Range("I2").Value
    Const MailCC = Worksheets("Mappings").Range("I2").Value
    
    MailSub = "Please review " & Range("Subject")
    MailTxt = Range("Body")
     '*************************************************  ********
     
     'Turns off screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
     'Makes a copy of the active sheet and save it to
     'a temporary file
    Worksheets("Commentary").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    FileName = "Commentary.xls"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill "C:\" & FileName
    On Error GoTo 0
    wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\" & FileName
     
     'Creates and shows the outlook mail item
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        .To = MailTo
        .CC = MailCC
        .Subject = MailSub
        .Body = MailTxt
        .Attachments.Add wb.FullName
        .Display
    End With
     
     'Deletes the temporary file
    wb.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill wb.FullName
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
     
     'Restores screen updating and release Outlook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Read this article carefully. You will find your solution. https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways for getting the job done:

1. You can create an HTML string based on the Excel's range data and set the `HTMLBody` property of the Outlook item:

   ```
   mailItem.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
   ```

   The `RangetoHTML` function is listed below (Ron de Bruin):

   ```
   Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
   End Function
   ```
2. The Word object model allows copying and pasting data between Office application. You can get the `Document` instance from the Word object model using the [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property which returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. So, if you copy the required data in Excel you could use the [Range.Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.paste) method from the Word object model to insert the contents of the `Clipboard` at the specified range.